# Banach space valued random variable

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space valued random variable. 
Is there a characteristic function of $X$ in this case? How it is defined if there is one?Are there any applications of this function in this high dimensional case? For example proving limit theorems?
What if $X$ takes values in a (locally convex) topological vector space?

Comment: If $X$ takes values in a Hilbert space you can generalize Fourier transforms directly: $\hat \mu(\xi)=\int e^{-2\pi i \cdot \langle x\mid \xi\rangle}\, d\mu(x)$. I'm not sure about uses in probability theory, though... For arbitrary Banach spaces, I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: What's about replacing the inner product by an element of the dual space in the Banach space case?

Comment: Well, I suppose that would work, at least formally. Then $\hat\mu$ would be a complex-valued function on the dual space. Note that the Banach space in question must be real, otherwise there's no reason for the integral to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, a characteristic function or Fourier transform for a random variable $X$ valued in a Banach space $B$ is usually defined as the function $\phi_X : B^* \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\phi_X(f) = \mathbb{E} e^{i f(X)}$.  Here $B^*$ is the continuous dual of $B$.

For example, we say $X$ is Gaussian iff $f(X)$ is Gaussian for all $f \in B^*$, iff $\phi_X(f) = e^{-q(f)/2}$ where $q$ is a quadratic form on $B^*$.

Comment: Is $\phi_{X_n}\rightarrow \phi_{X}$ equivalent to convergence in distribution?

Comment: @user114170: I don't know.  Some Googling suggests the answer may be "no".  I'd suggest you ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are two definitions for Banach values random variables:
1.  The Pettis integral: $E(X) = Y$ means $E(\xi(X)) = \xi(Y)$ for any $\xi$ in the dual space;
2.  The Bochner integral: $X$ is a limit of simple functions, and is defined just as the regular real valued integral.

I think most books and papers go with the Bochner integral.  This is equivalent to $X$ being measurable, and taking values in a separable subspace except on a set of measure zero.

A characteristic function is obviously defined in a Pettis integral like manner, and I think this is the only way.

An interesting example of a non-Bochner inegrable function: Let $[0,1] \to M([0,1])$, where $M$ denotes the space of signed Radon measures (ie the dual of $C([0,1])$, given by the map $x\mapsto \delta_x$.

Comment: But the characteristic function is the integral of a scalar-valued function, so there's no need for any of these things, is there?